# expressing uncertainty on a definitive statement containing "can"

Tags: phrase-request, auxiliary-verbs

In math or computer science there are a lot of definitive statements that can be formulated with "can" / "cannot".

Examples:

> - "If the last digit of a natural number is 0 then it cannot be prime."
> - "A natural number can only be even or odd."
> - "If I divide an even number by 2, the result can (still) be even."

I am looking for ways to give such a statement some uncertainty to express the following: If I did not make any mistakes, then it definitely must be that way (because it follows from some irrevocable laws / logic / axioms...). But I am not sure that I did not make any mistakes, so please, dear reader / listener, check it yourself and correct me if I am wrong!

**Are there compact ways to give the "can (only) / cannot be" a touch of uncertainty in the above sense?**

In my native language - German - I could just add a "should (be)" and reorder some words to get that effect.

I think - please correct me if I am wrong - that this is usually possible in English, too, but with normal (non-auxiliary) verbs. E.g.:

> - *person A:* "Is she painting the wall now?"
> - *person B, certain:* "Yes, she is painting the wall now."
> - *person B, uncertain:* "(I'm  not sure, but) she should be painting the wall now."

But in my ears, using a combination of "can" and "should" sounds wrong. So what options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

You can indicate uncertainty by backshifting: shall -> should and can -> could.

> person A: "Is she painting the wall now?"
>   person B, certain: "Yes, she is painting the wall now."
>   person B, uncertain: "I'm  not sure, but she **could** be painting the wall now."

Note that you can't use **could not** to imply uncertainty, for example you can use this idiomatic expression of somebody who definitely has no organizational skills:

> He couldn't organize a piss-up in a brewery.

To express negative capability and uncertainty, you would have to use **probably**:

> person B, uncertain: "I'm not sure, but she probably isn't painting the wall now."

Comment: I corrected the example regarding simple present (thanks for pointing it out); you can remove that part of your answer if you like.